# How to change the background of the textfield in a JavaFX editable combobox/datepicker

Tags: css, javafx

I have a function that checks the inputs of a form (textfields, comboboxes, and datepickers) and if any of them are empty it changes the background color to a light red

```
public void checkForm() {
    if (clientIdInput.getText().equals("")) {
        clientIdInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(clientNameInput.getText().equals("")) {
        clientNameInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(clientPhoneNumberInput.getText().equals("")) {
        clientPhoneNumberInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(trainerIdInput.getText().equals("")) {
        trainerIdInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(trainerNameInput.getText().equals("")) {
        trainerNameInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(membershipTypeOptions.getValue() == null) {
        membershipTypeOptions.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(membershipStartDateInput.getValue() == null) {
        membershipStartDateInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(membershipEndDateInput.getValue() == null) {
        membershipEndDateInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(paymentMethodOptions.getValue() == null) {
        paymentMethodOptions.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }

    if(paymentAmountInput.getText().equals("")) {
        paymentAmountInput.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F5D3D0");
    }
}
```

And it works fine except for the datepicker and editable combobox because they seem to have a textbox layered on top that isn't affected by the -fx-background-color property. So my question is basically just how do I make both backgrounds have the same color? And as a small side question is there a more efficient way to do the purpose of this function rather than 10 if statements?

Here is how it looks like once the function runs:
[image: img]

Comment: Use `-fx-control-inner-background` instead of `-fx-background-color`. To make the code more efficient just do the obvious thing and define a method that takes a `TextField` and call it for all the text fields (`List.of(textField1, textField2, ...).forEach(this::checkTextField)` and define another method that takes a `ComboBoxBase<?>` and do the same for all the combo boxes and date pickers.

Comment: @James_D So I tried `-fx-control-inner-background` and what it did was change the prompt text color not the background color. All I did was replace `-fx-background-color` with it was I supposed to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me to replace `-fx-background-color` with the looked-up color `-fx-control-inner-background`, which is used by the default stylesheet to color text fields.

```
package org.jamesd.examples.validate;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        ComboBox<String> combo1 = makeCombo();
        ComboBox<String> combo2 = makeCombo();
        DatePicker dp1 = new DatePicker();
        DatePicker dp2 = new DatePicker();
        
        VBox root = new VBox(10, tf1, tf2, combo1, combo2, dp1, dp2);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        
        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (! (validate(tf -> tf.getText().isEmpty(), tf1, tf2)) && 
                    (! validate(cb -> cb.getValue() == null, combo1, combo2, dp1, dp2)) ) {
                System.out.println("Success!");
            }
        });
        
        root.getChildren().add(submit);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private ComboBox<String> makeCombo() {
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        combo.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three");
        combo.setEditable(true);
        return combo ;
    }
    
    private <C extends Control> boolean validate(Predicate<C> invalidTest, C... controls) {
        boolean result = true ;
        for (C control : controls) {
            
            if (invalidTest.test(control)) {
                control.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: #F5D3D0;");
                result = false ;
            } else {
                control.setStyle("");
            }
        }
        return result ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

An approach that gives you a bit more control is to set a custom CSS pseudoclass on the control, and then to use an external stylesheet.

Comment: This does work but I figured out what the problem is on my side, when I add the css file I am using to style the elements initially for some reason it makes `-fx-control-inner-background` have no effect, so I will instead try the second option you mentioned. Thanks :)

Comment: @AhmedNoaman You’re probably setting `-fx-background-color` in the style sheet, so it no longer takes the value of `-fx-control-inner-background`. Generally (this is an opinion) I find it works better to adjust the looked-up colors defined in modena, instead of the underlying properties.